# Make a calendar in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

```
 const cal_days =['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
 const cal_months =['Jan', 'Feb', 'March', 'April',
'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
 const daysInMonth =[31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
 const curr =new Date();
 var d = new Date();
 var n = d.getMonth();
 var yearName = d.getFullYear();
 var monName = cal_months[n];
 var firstDay = new Date(yearName,n, 1);
 var startD = firstDay.getDay();
 var num= daysinmonth[n];
 var day=1;

 var Show = React.createClass({
 numrow:function(){
 //var day = 1;
for (var i = 1; i <=6; i++) {
for (var j = 0; j <= 6; j++) { 
   if (day <= num && (i > 0 || j >= startD)) {
    return (<td>{i}</td>);
    day++; 
     }
    if (day > n) {
        break;
      } else 
      {
        return (<tr></tr>);
      }
    }
     }
      },

    render:function(){
    var daysname= cal_days.map(function(day){
   for(var i = 0; i <= 6; i++ ){
   return <td>{day}</td>;}
   })
   return (
   <div>
    <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      {daysname}
      </tr>
      <tr>
      {this.numrow()}
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
   ) 
    }
   })
```

---

[image: This is the output of the program]

I am on way to make a calendar in reactjs. I am beginner in Reactjs.I want to displays days 123..so on. Why does the numrow function prints only 1.
I am also attaching my ouput.(This is not the full program,just a prt of it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array in `numrow` function and push each element in that array then return whole array in end. It should work

```
numrow:function(){
    //var day = 1;
    var rows = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <=6; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j <= 6; j++) { 
            if (day <= num && (i > 0 || j >= startD)) {
                rows.push(<td>{i}</td>)
                day++; 
            }
            if (day > n) {
                 break;
            } else 
            {
            rows.push(<tr></tr>)
            }
        }
    }
     return rows;
   },
```

my suggestion is when you post your code on stackoverflow name your variables properly(not i and j) so your code can be more readable.